# while tokenization I'm encountering this error

Tags: python-3.x, tokenize, keyerror

I am a newbie to programming and I tried to do some interesting stuffs and ended up here, while string tokenizing I encountered this error while I can't solve this atmost

**code:**

```
import re
def cw(text):
    counts=dict()
    text=text.lower()
    words=re.split(r'[^\w]',text)
    for i in words:
        print(words)
        if i !="":
            if i not in words:
                counts[i]=1
            else:
                counts[i]+=1
    return counts
def input():
    with open("input.txt",'r') as f:
        text=f.read()
        counts=cw(text)
        sort=sorted(counts.items(),key=lambda pair: pair[1],reverse=True)
        print(sort)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    input()
```

**Error is:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/surya/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/okay.py", line 35, in <module>
    input()
  File "C:/Users/surya/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/okay.py", line 27, in input
    counts=cw(text)
  File "C:/Users/surya/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/okay.py", line 17, in cw
    counts[i]+=1
KeyError: 'as'
```

Comment: you need to check `if i not in counts` or use defaultdict() instead of dict(). To use defaultdict(), you need to import `from collections import defaultdict`.

Comment: thanks for that comment , now it works charm I just messed up the logic "if i not in counts" worked :D